# How to determine a number of grouped records in Rails?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, group-by

A table has this structure and data in there:

```
id | car     | location | ...
-----------------------------
1  | BMW     | US       | ...
2  | Audi    | US       | ...
3  | Audi    | US       | ...
4  | Porsche | CA       | ...
5  | Audi    | US       | ...
```

I am loading and grouping data in a usual way:

```
@cars = Cars.where('location = ?', location).group('car')
```

I'd need to display in a view a number of grouped data - in this case, I would need to print how much of data is in the US for example; so the desired output would be like:

```
BMW - 1 car
Audi - 3 cars
```

How to get a number of grouped rows?

Comment: DO not know about `ruby` but in mysql it will be as `select car,count(*) as total from table where location = 'US' group by car`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Car.where(location: location).group(:car).count #=> e.g. {'BMW' => 1}
```

Just FYI, you can also group by location AND car.

```
Car.group(:location, :car).count #=> e.g. {['US', 'BMW'] => 1}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you, the first query is what I need! Just a question - I use the first query and I am receiving the results as this - `{'BMW' => 1}` - but is there any way to being able to work also with other attributes of the `Car` model? Because right now, I have only car maker and a number of cars in a country. Thank you.

Comment: No problem. Mark my post as the answer and vote up this comment if it helped. And you can get the other attributes by adding them through a "select" clause. However, I would recommend keeping it simple and doing `location_car_count = Car.group(:location, :car).count` and then you can iterate over your `Car.where(location: location)` relation/array. You will have access to all car attributes and to get the count, you will only need to `car_count = location_car_count[[car.location, car.name]]` Here: http://www.codeshare.io/iGi4F

Comment: Hmm.. that would work, but wouldn't be there to do it in a single query? There are two queries right now, which could be a problem for a big table (mine is over 1M rows).

Comment: `cars = Car.where(location: location).group(:car).select("#{Car.column_names}.join(',')", COUNT(car) AS car_count)` and then `cars.first.car_count #=> what you want` But keep in mind that 'cars' won't include all cars in your database as the results will be grouped.